# What does an arrayList<Observer> hold in it

Tags: java, observer-pattern, observers

So, I have created 2 interfaces 
One is called Observer and the other one Subject
Observer contains update() method and
Subject contains Boolean registerObserver(Observer o), Boolean removeObserver(Observer o) and void notifyObservers().

When I need to define the methods of Subject in a class I do not understand how should I use
the ArrayList observers.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If a subject has a collection of observers presumably when the subject does something "observable" then you'd notify all the observers.

Comment: This sounds like you have an assignment to implement the `Subject` interface, and you were given the hint that you should use an `ArrayList<Observer>` to do so.  So in general, `registerObserver()` should *add* to your ArrayList, `removeObserver()` should *remove* from the ArrayList, and `notifyObservers()` should loop over the ArrayList and notify each observer therein.

Comment: It is actually a piece of code I was given to study and understand, but it is not pretty clear to me what :
- an observer is (is it a class?) 
- a subject is   (is it an object?)                                                                                                       and why I need to hold the observers in an ArrayList<Observer>      Thank you for your response, I apologise if I am not clear.